# Rust calling mutable self function from mutable self function

Tags: rust

In the example below, I want to call `spin` for every `smol_socket_handle` which is simply an `usize`.

```
pub fn spin_all(&mut self) -> u8 {
        for (smol_socket_handle, _) in self.smol_sockets.iter_mut() {
            self.spin(smol_socket_handle.clone());
        }
        0
    }
pub fn spin(&mut self, smol_socket_handle: usize) -> u8 {
```

The problem is that I borrow `self` as mutable twice. Once when `spin_all` is called, and once again when we call `spin`. I absolutely need `spin` to work on a `&mut self`. How can I make `spin_all` call `spin` lots of times for a mutable `self`?

**UPDATE:**

So if I understood correctly,

```
    for (smol_socket_handle, smol_socket) in self.smol_sockets.iter_mut() {
        self.spin(smol_socket_handle.clone());
    }
```

expands into

```
{
    //borrows self mutably
    let mut _iter = std::iter::IntoIterator::into_iter(self.smol_sockets.iter_mut());
    loop {
        match _iter.next() {
            Some(loop_variable) => {
                //tries to borrow self mutably again while it's still borrowed into `_iter`
                self.spin(loop_variable.clone());
            },
            None => break,
        }
    }
}
```

?

Comment: Rust prevents this because it can cause a data race. You must ensure that no data race can occur, e.g. by cloning the sockets before iterating over them: `self.smol_sockets.clone().into_iter()`. Not sure if this works though, since your code is incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that I borrow self as mutable twice. Once when spin_all is called, and once again when we call spin.

No, that is not the problem. The mutable `&mut self` of spin_all is reused by `spin`, there is no conflict (in fact it would not work otherwise, as `self.spin` would try to create a mutable borrow from an immutable borrow, which would fail).

The problem is that you're creating a mutable borrow for `self.smol_sockets.iter_mut()`, and a separate and overlapping borrow for `self.spin()`.

You should either avoid the borrow on the sockets iterable by cloning it as Aloso noted, or give `spin` an index / key into the iterable so that it does the borrowing internally.

Comment: I dont get it. `self.smol_sockets.iter_mut()` borrows `smol_sockets`, not `self`. Can you explain to me?

Comment: `smol_sockets` is owned by `self`, so mutably borrowing `smol_sockets` necessarily borrows `self` mutably first.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer for me was to declare the mutable borrows in the second function. If `foo` calls `bar`, do the mutable borrowing inside `bar` instead of passing `bar` a mutable reference, which doesn't work.

Do this:

```
pub fn foo(&mut self, thingid: u32) {
    //stuff
    self.bar(&thingid);
}
pub fn bar(&mut self, thingid: u32) {
    self.things.get_mut(&thingid).unwrap();
    //stuff
}
```

Don't do this as it causes an error (`error[E0502]: cannot borrow *self as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable`).

```
pub fn foo(&mut self, thingid: u32) {
    //stuff
    let thing = self.things.get_mut(&thingid).unwrap();
    self.bar(thing);
}
pub fn bar(&mut self, thing: &mut Thing) {
    //stuff
}
```